# Way to select numerous non-continuous dates with dateInput in Shiny?

Tags: r, date, datepicker, shiny

`dateInput` seems to be restricted to selecting a single date.

`dateRangeInput` only allows you to select a range of dates *in a row*.

Is there a way to select *multiple* dates that do not fall in a row (i.e., dates that are non-continuous)?

What I really want is a calendar in which I can select (click-on) multiple dates resulting in all of those dates being selected as separate input values.

For example, if possible, I'd like to be able to do this:

[image: shiny calendar with multiple selected dates]

Comment: This is not possible with base shiny. Alternatively you could use a `selectInput` which allows selecting multiple values but without date picker, or use several `dateInput`. You can also build one in javascript using http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

In shinyWidgets package, you have `airDatepicker` which does just that, using argument `multiple=TRUE`. Have a look at [this page](https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyWidgets/man/airDatepicker.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help someone in need. You can select multiple dates from the date picker. The dates are kept in an ordered timeline. A click on the selected date removes that date from the list. The dates in the list can be accessed by `dates$df$date`. The observe code was from another SO post that unfortunately I could not find anymore. Feel free to link that post in if you find/know it. The random id is used to identify the items in the dataframe and the uiComponents list. As you might notice, it may not work correctly one lucky day.

[image]

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Multiple Dates",  windowTitle = "Dates"),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 2,
                 dateInput("date", "Date", value = "2019-05-31"),
                 tags$b("Selected"),
                 uiOutput("container")
    ),
    column(width = 10,
              verbatimTextOutput("text")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  container <- reactiveValues(uiComponents = list())

  # empty data frame
  dates <- reactiveValues(df = data.frame(matrix(ncol=2,nrow=0, dimnames=list(NULL, c("id", "date")))))

  ###### Monitor changes in date-picker and add new dates to uiComponents
  observeEvent(input$date, {
    isolate({
      rnd <- as.integer(runif(1,1e5,1e6-1))
      dates$df <- rbind(dates$df, data.frame(id = rnd, date = input$date))
      dates$df <- dates$df[order(dates$df$date), ] # sort by date
      container$uiComponents <- NULL  # delete list and re-write it from df
      for (i in 1:NROW(dates$df)) {
        container$uiComponents <- append(
          container$uiComponents,
          list(
            list(
              "link" = actionLink(paste0("link", dates$df$id[i]), label = as.character(dates$df$date[i])),
              "br" = br()
            )
          )
        )
      }
    })
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)

  ###### Monitor and locate click events from list
  observe({
    if(length(container$uiComponents) == 0) return()
    # links <- lapply(container$uiComponents, `[[`, "link")
    readLinkID <- sapply(container$uiComponents, function(x) {
      x$link$attribs$id
    })
    readLinkVals <- sapply(readLinkID, function(x) input[[x]])
    if(any(sapply(readLinkVals, is.null))) return()
    if(all(readLinkVals == 0)) return()
    isolate({
      container$uiComponents[[which(readLinkVals > 0)]] <- NULL
      dates$df <- dates$df[-which(readLinkVals > 0), ]
    })
  })

  output$container <- renderUI({
    container$uiComponents
  })

  output$text <- renderPrint({
    print(dates$df)
    str(container$uiComponents)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score -1):

I rewrite the dateInput function.

And also you can have a look at : [enter link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152960/display-only-months-in-daterangeinput-or-dateinput-for-a-shiny-app-r-programmin/32171132)

```
  mydateInput <- function(inputId, label, value = NULL, min = NULL, max = NULL,
                        format = "yyyy-mm-dd", startview = "month", weekstart = 0, language = "en", minviewmode="months",
                        width = NULL) {

  # If value is a date object, convert it to a string with yyyy-mm-dd format
  # Same for min and max
  if (inherits(value, "Date"))  value <- format(value, "%Y-%m-%d")
  if (inherits(min,   "Date"))  min   <- format(min,   "%Y-%m-%d")
  if (inherits(max,   "Date"))  max   <- format(max,   "%Y-%m-%d")

  htmltools::attachDependencies(
    tags$div(
             class = "shiny-date-input form-group shiny-input-container",
             style = if (!is.null(width)) paste0("width: ", validateCssUnit(width), ";"),

             controlLabel(inputId, label),
             tags$input(id = inputId, type = "text",
                        # datepicker class necessary for dropdown to display correctly
                        class = "form-control datepicker",
                        `data-date-language` = language,
                        `data-date-weekstart` = weekstart,
                        `data-date-format` = format,
                        `data-date-start-view` = startview,
                        `data-date-min-view-mode` = minviewmode,
                        `data-min-date` = min,
                        `data-max-date` = max,
                        `data-initial-date` = value,
                        `data-date-multidate` = 'true'

             )
    ),
    datePickerDependency
  )
}

`%AND%` <- function(x, y) {
  if (!is.null(x) && !is.na(x))
    if (!is.null(y) && !is.na(y))
      return(y)
  return(NULL)
}

controlLabel <- function(controlName, label) {
  label %AND% tags$label(class = "control-label", `for` = controlName, label)
}

datePickerDependency <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "bootstrap-datepicker", "1.6.4", c(href = "shared/datepicker"),
  script = "js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js",
  stylesheet = "css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css",
  # Need to enable noConflict mode. See #1346.
  head = "<script>
  (function() {
  var datepicker = $.fn.datepicker.noConflict();
  $.fn.bsDatepicker = datepicker;
  })();
  </script>")


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152960/display-only-months-in-daterangeinput-or-dateinput-for-a-shiny-app-r-programmin/32171132
```