# Select month and year only

Tags: r, date, input, shiny, flexdashboard

do you know how can I only propose to users to just select : month and year.

I tried this :

```
dateInput("DATE", "Choix de la date", value = "2018-10", min = "2018-07", max = "2019-06",
          format = "yyyy-mm", startview = "year", weekstart = 0,
          language = "fr", width = NULL)
```

But it doesn't work as expected. Thanks

Comment: What is `dateInput`??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152960/display-only-months-in-daterangeinput-or-dateinput-for-a-shiny-app-r-programmin

Comment: thanks  @PeterDieter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display only months in dateRangeInput or dateInput for a shiny app \[R programming\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152960/display-only-months-in-daterangeinput-or-dateinput-for-a-shiny-app-r-programmin)